# Replacing "\n" but not "\n\n"

Tags: ruby, gsub

How to replace `"\n"` but not `"\n\n"` etc. with `"  \n"`?

```
text1 = "Hello\nWorld"
text1.sub! "\n", "  \n"
=> "Hello  \nWorld"

text2 = "Hello\n\nWorld"
text2.sub! "\n\n", "  \n"
=> "Hello  \n\nWorld"
SHOULD BE: => "Hello\n\nWorld"
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from your examples what you want to happen.  Why should the first example have spaces in the result, but the second should not?

Comment: The intent looks like it's trying to add hard line breaks in Markdown syntax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/`, which matches a `\n` only when it's not prefixed with another `\n` and not followed by a `\n`.

```
text1 = "Hello\nWorld"
# => "Hello\nWorld"
text1.sub /(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/, "  \n"
# => "Hello  \nWorld"
text2 = "Hello\n\nWorld"
# => "Hello\n\nWorld"
text2.sub /(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/, "  \n"
# => "Hello\n\nWorld"
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way:

```
r = /\n+/

"Hello\nWorld".sub(r) { |s| (s.size==1) ? " \n" : s }
  #=> "Hello  \nWorld"

"Hello\n\nWorld".sub(r) { |s| (s.size==1) ? " \n" : s }
  #=> "Hello\n\nWorld"
```

and one more:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = k }.update("\n"=>"  \n")
  #=> {"\n"=>"  \n"}

"Hello\nWorld".sub(r,h)
   #=> "Hello  \nWorld" 
"Hello\n\nWorld".sub(r,h)
   #=> "Hello\n\nWorld"
```

In the latter method, each string of one or more consecutive newline characters is passed to the hash. If it's a single newline, `"\n"` is replaced with `h["\n"] #=> "  \n"`. If it's two or more newlines, say `s = "\n\n"`, and `h` does not have a key equal to `s` (initally it won't), the key-value pair `s=>s` will be added to `h` (because of the default value defined for the hash) and `s` will be replaced by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you could use:

```
string = "Hello\nWorld"
string.split("\n") == string.split("\n").reject(&:empty?) ? string.sub!("\n", " \n") : string
  #=> "Hello \nWorld"

string = "Hello\n\nWorld"
string.split("\n") == string.split("\n").reject(&:empty?) ? string.sub!("\n", " \n") : string
  #=> "Hello\n\nWorld"
```